# Constructor function didn't save querySelector(x).value

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I am working on a small APP for calculating Budgets and i am stuck on a problem i don't understand. I used a constructor for getting the user inputs in a few input fields.

I tried to setup this part in a constructor to learn more about prototyping and constructor functions and to challenge myself. I don't get why the constructor `GetInput` not holding my input.values

```html
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
const addType = document.querySelector('.add__type').value;
const description = document.querySelector('.add__description').value
const addValue = document.querySelector('.add__value').value;

// EVENTLISTENER Constructor:
function EventListner(selector, listner, fnt) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.listner = listner;
  this.fnt = fnt;
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(listner, fnt);
};

function GetInput(operator, description, value) {
  this.operator = operator;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
}

const inputData = new GetInput(addType, description, addValue);
console.log(inputData);

const clickListener = new EventListner('.add__btn', 'click', () => {
  if (description.value == '' || addValue.value == '') {
    // MAKE SURE DESCRIPTION AND VALUE IS NOT EMPTY
    alert('description and value can\'t be empty');
    return;
  }
  const inputData = new GetInput(addType, description, addValue);
  console.log(inputData);
});

const enterKeyListener = new EventListner('.add__value', 'keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (description.value == '' || addValue.value == '') {
      // MAKE SURE DESCRIPTION AND VALUE IS NOT EMPTY
      alert('description and value can\'t be empty');
      return;
    }
    // ON ENTER SAVE VALUES IN AN ARRAY
    // IF PLUS INTO incomeArr, ON MINUS INTO expenseArr
    console.log('enter pressed');
    const inputData = new GetInput(addType, description, addValue);
    console.log(inputData);
  }
});
```

Output is:

```
GetInput {operator: "inc", description: "", value: ""}
```

Only works when i:

```
document.querySelector('.add__value').value;
```

directly into the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial values are empty for the input fields. And your code is executing right away. That's why you are getting empty value for those fields.You can try adding some predefined values for those input field.

**Code with predefined value for the input fields :**

```js
const addType = document.querySelector('.add__type').value;
const description = document.querySelector('.add__description').value
const addValue = document.querySelector('.add__value').value;


function GetInput(operator, description, value) {
  this.operator = operator;
  this.description = description;
  this.value = value;
}

const inputData = new GetInput(addType, description, addValue);
console.log(inputData);
```

```html
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" value="mydesc" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" value="2" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`Note :` You need to add event listener to listen to any change in your input field values. If user type anything then you can proceed to instantiate your constructor function

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this issue because you need to trigger an event to for calculate, and one more thing you have to use something else other then const, because you cannot reinitialize value in constant variables, Current code is execute on loading page, So the values is initialized to that will not change

```
const addType = document.querySelector('.add__type').value;
const description = document.querySelector('.add__description').value
const addValue = document.querySelector('.add__value').value;
```

So please change const with var or let, Or you can set default value to description and value